# How to print two statements from different functions on the same line in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print two output statements on the same line in Python 2.7 (or 3.4). The print statements don't come one after the other Like print a/ print b. My program takes 329 (say) and returns that value in words - three hundred twenty nine. So it will determine the 300 part and print it then the 29 part and print that.

```
if (main == hundreds[index]):
    print hundreds_words[index]
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        print twenties_words[location]
```

I want to print the twenty nine on the same line as the three hundred. I suppose I could try and rig up a solution but I would like to know if Python has a procedure to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.  You just need to tell `print` not to add a new-line after the first one.  In python2, you do this by adding a trailing comma: `print mystring,`.  In python3, `print` is a function that has the `end` keyword argument: `print(mystring, end="")`

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to rewrite your number-to-words function and have it return a string instead of printing it.

The more involved way is to redirect `stdout` to capture the `print` output as a string.

**Edit:** looks like I made it more complicated than necessary; you could instead try

```
output_words = []
if (main == hundreds[index]):
    output_words.append(hundreds_words[index])
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        output_words.append(twenties_words[location])
return " ".join(output_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2 you can end a `print` statement with a `,` to indicate not to terminate in a newline, e.g.:

```
print hundreds_words[index],
```

In python 3 (or py2 with `from __future__ import print_function`) you explicitly need to define the `end`, e.g.:

```
print(hundreds_words[index], end=' ')
```

But ideally you would just collect all the result up in a `list` and `join()` them at the end...

```
result = []
if (main == hundreds[index]):
    result.append(hundreds_words[index])
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        result.append(twenties_words[location])

print(' '.join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Always design functions to **return** values, and not to *print* them (it's much more Pythonic!). Therefore, you should modify your code this way:

```
# FOR PYTHON 2.x

if (main == hundreds[index]):
    print hundreds_words[index], # Note the comma
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        print twenties_words[location]

# FOR PYTHON 3.x

if (main == hundreds[index]):
    print(hundreds_words[index], end=" ") # end=" " will override the default '\n' and leave a space after the string
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        print(twenties_words[location])
```

There's also a third option, more scalable: to **wrap** all datas in a list, and then print everything.

```
printable = []

if (main == hundreds[index]):
    printable += hundreds_words[index]
for location in range (0, 10):
    if (difference == twenties[location]):
        printable += twenties_words[location]

print(" ".join(printable))
```